# Why this code return Nothing instead of throwing exception

Tags: haskell, monads

Could you explain me why following code returns `Nothing` insteaf od exception "zero" ?

```
Just 0 >>= (\ x -> if (x == 0) then fail "zero" else Just (x + 1) )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you are using the `Maybe` instance of `Monad`. This instance defines `fail` as `Nothing`.